# Why aren't my weights being updated?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying this very simple neural net which tells if a number is odd or even.
labels: [1, 0] means it's even. I'm using two output neuron because I'm using softmax function.

My code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

data_in = [
            [1],
            [2],
            [3]
            ]
data_lbl = [
            [0, 1],
            [1, 0],
            [0, 1]
            ]


# HP

learning_rate = 0.1
epochs = 10000

ip = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 1])
labels = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 2])
w1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, 2]))
w2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, 2]))

l1 = tf.matmul(ip, w1)
l2 = tf.matmul(l1, w2)
l2 = tf.nn.softmax(l2)

loss = tf.reduce_mean((labels - l2)**2)
train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)

sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for epoch in range(epochs):
    _, err = sess.run([train, loss], feed_dict={ip: data_in, labels: data_lbl})
    print(err)

print(sess.run(l2, feed_dict={ip: [[2], [5], [7]]}))
# [it is, it's not]
# 1 = even

sess.close()
```

My error is not changing and I'm getting wrong answers. Suggestions?

Comment: The parity of a number isn't an easy problem for a NN to solve. Have you tried other problems first? Like a simple AND gate? Your training set is also quite small, and hardcoded. You could fairly easily use a function to generate training data to expose the net to more scenarios.

Comment: Also you don't have any activation function on your hidden layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple issues here, fixing those should at least give you something that learns *something*:

- You don't have any nonlinearities in your network other than the final softmax. You need nonlinearities, as parity is not a linear function.
- Your intermediate layers are quite small.
- Your training samples are very limited.
- You don't have biases.

In addition, parity is a concept that is very hard to learn so it generalizes to numbers not seen in the training set.